# Como evitar en Django cuando uso un bloque transaction.atomic y aplico un rollback borra una parte del código ejecutado

Tags: python, django, postgresql, orm

Esto creando un sistema de ventas y tengo un problema, al querer realizar una venta y al encontrar un error en la generación del comprobante electrónico reverso toda la factura pero al mismo tiempo tengo el método que crear el comprobante electrónico crea un registro de auditoria con el error pero al aplicar el rollback se borra todo y no deseo que se borre todo sino solo la factura pero el registro de la auditoría no.

Tengo el siguiente código en la vista para guardar la venta.

```
          with transaction.atomic():
                iva = float(Company.objects.first().iva) / 100
                sale = Sale()
                sale.company = Company.objects.first()
                sale.environment_type = sale.company.environment_type
                sale.receipts = Receipts.objects.get(code=VOUCHER_TYPE[0][0])
                sale.voucher_number = sale.generate_voucher_number()
                sale.voucher_number_full = sale.get_voucher_number_full()
                sale.employee_id = request.user.id
                sale.client_id = int(request.POST['client'])
                sale.payment_method = request.POST['payment_method']
                sale.iva = iva
                sale.dscto = float(request.POST['dscto']) / 100
                sale.save()
                for i in json.loads(request.POST['products']):
                    product = Product.objects.get(pk=i['id'])
                    detail = SaleDetail()
                    detail.sale_id = sale.id
                    detail.product_id = product.id
                    detail.cant = int(i['cant'])
                    detail.price = float(i['price_current'])
                    detail.dscto = float(i['dscto']) / 100
                    detail.save()
                    sale.calculate_detail()
                    detail.product.stock -= detail.cant
                    detail.product.save()
                sale.calculate_invoice()
                if sale.payment_method == PAYMENT_METHOD[1][0]:
                    sale.end_credit = request.POST['end_credit']
                    sale.cash = 0.00
                    sale.change = 0.00
                    sale.save()
                    ctas_collect = CtasCollect()
                    ctas_collect.sale_id = sale.id
                    ctas_collect.date_joined = sale.date_joined
                    ctas_collect.end_date = sale.end_credit
                    ctas_collect.debt = sale.total
                    ctas_collect.saldo = sale.total
                    ctas_collect.save()
                else:
                    sale.cash = float(request.POST['cash'])
                    sale.change = float(request.POST['change'])
                sale.save()
                result = sale.generate_electronic_invoice()
                if result.get('resp'):
                    print_url = reverse_lazy('sale_admin_print_invoice', kwargs={'pk': sale.id})
                    data = {'print_url': str(print_url)}
                else:
                    transaction.set_rollback(True)
                    data = result
```

Lo que deseo es que solo se aplique el rollback hasta la linea del **sale.save()** porque cuando se ejecuta la linea **result = sale.generate_electronic_invoice()** se genera internamente un registro de auditoria y preguntar sobre variable result que es un diccionario y tiene un key llamado resp (una variable booleana) y da False aplico el rollback pero se borra todo y solo deseo que se borre lo de las entidades de **Sale y SaleDetail**.

He aplicado el uso de **savepoint, savepoint_rollback** y creando otro **transaction.atomic** para solo esa parte de código pero igual no me funciona, o quisiera saber si al menos existe alguna forma o decorador que se le pueda poner a una función para que evite que se aplique el rollback porque existe algo @transaction.non_atomic_requests pero es una vista no una función.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para evitar que el rollback borre una parte del código ejecutado en Django, es posible utilizar puntos de guardado (savepoints) dentro de una transacción. Un savepoint es una marca dentro de una transacción que permite volver a ese punto en caso de error, sin tener que revertir todo el trabajo realizado en la transacción.

En tu caso, podrías utilizar savepoints para marcar el punto donde se realiza la creación del registro de auditoría. De esta manera, si ocurre un error al generar el comprobante electrónico, puedes revertir la transacción hasta ese punto, conservando el registro de auditoría.

Para utilizar savepoints, puedes usar el método savepoint() de la conexión de la base de datos:

```
from django.db import transaction

with transaction.atomic():
    # ... código previo ...
    save_id = transaction.savepoint()  # guardar un savepoint

    result = sale.generate_electronic_invoice()
    if result.get('resp'):
        # ... código posterior ...
    else:
        transaction.savepoint_rollback(save_id)  # revertir hasta el savepoint
        data = result
```

En este ejemplo, se guarda un savepoint después de crear la instancia de Sale y antes de generar el comprobante electrónico. Si ocurre un error al generar el comprobante, se revierte la transacción hasta el savepoint guardado, sin afectar el registro de auditoría.

También es importante destacar que el uso de savepoints dentro de una transacción debe ser manejado cuidadosamente, ya que un uso incorrecto podría generar inconsistencias en la base de datos. Además, es recomendable limitar el alcance de una transacción a lo mínimo necesario para evitar bloqueos innecesarios de la base de datos.